# rss feed to be published on the page

Tags: rss

i am looking to develop a webpage in html in which i need to publish the rss feeds.
users will submit the rss url at one page & the feeds need to be displayed in a different page

Comment: please elaborate, this is very terse.

Comment: Hi Sanjay,

I think you need to do a bit more investigation--as it stands right now, your question is so general, it's not possible to answer it.  Either that or you need to specify a lot more details.

Answer (score 0):

Geez, the question lacks detail. Assuming that you want to use php (wild guess, heh), use http://simplepie.org/ to parse the feed.